# Permission denied while creating ssh key using ssh-keygen Git bash Windows 10 Enterprise

Tags: windows, git, ssh, ssh-keygen

I am trying to create ssh key using git bash ssh-keygen. After setting file name and passphrases `Saving key "sshKey" failed: Permission denied` error appears.

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "email@bla.com" -b 4096
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/c/Users/user1/.ssh/id_rsa): sshKey
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Saving key "sshKey" failed: Permission denied
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved this problem by creating .ssh directory in `C:/Users/currentUser` and then open Git Bash and set path to newly created folder. After that generate ssh key using `ssh-keygen` and there is no `Permission denied error`.